# Minecraft title screen

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was looking for ways to create a custom menu screen when you first load up the game and I found a lot of tutorials on how to do it, but I want to have a still picture instead of a panorama and I have no idea how to get it. May someone please enlighten me on how to get a still Minecraft menu background?

Comment: It does not involve modding to change the panorama in the title screen, it is a resource pack that does it. I'm asking if in the resource pack there is a way to make the title screen a still image.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the clarification. I believe that resource packs are in scope for our site. Again, to the community, if I am mistaken please reply.

Comment: @FoodPuns This is a good question, but the clarification you gave, kindly edit that into the original question.